# getting the raw source from Firefox with javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am writing a program to validate web pages on a remote server.  It uses selenium RC to run Firefox with a battery of tests, so I can call arbitrary javascript.  When there is a failure I would like to log the page's generated HTML.  Now getting access to the DOM HTML is easy, But I am having real trouble finding a way to get at the source.  Thanks.

I should reiterate that I am not looking for the DOM, but the original unmodified source code. As can be seen through Right click -> view page source. Specifically if 
    `<Html>
     <body>
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td>
   fear the table data
   </td>
   </table>`

is the real HTML. Calls to `document.documentElement.outerHTML || document.documentElement.innerHTML` and `selenium.getHTMLSource()` will result in `<head> </head><body> <table> <tbody><tr> <td> fear the table data </td> </tr></tbody></table> </body>`

Comment: I'm currently doing this via additional requesting using http library, so every page actually fetched twice: with selenium and without. Also I often notice that viewing page source in Firefox comes with some lag, obviously browser do the same under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

XHR request the same page for the source, and just check `document.documentElement.outerHTML || document.documentElement.innerHTML` for the current state's source.

Comment: However. I am looking for the original unmodified html source code.

Comment: I said "XHR request the same page for the source".

Comment: I may be (more then likely) missing something, but if the page is dynamic it won't necessarily reload the same html that caused a bug.

Comment: Then you'd want the *current* source, which I also told you how to get.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  It's just that when I make that call on the poorly formatted html example I edited into my question, I get back a firefox DOM.  For example the inserted <head> </head>, <tbody>...</tbody>, and closing </body>.  This would be problematic for correctly logging the cause of bugs.  What are you doing that doesn't do that?

Comment: The current state's source is not the original page source.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something as simple as

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Comment: that gets the DOM at, least in Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are also using selenium, you can use `selenium.getHTMLSource()`. This will return the whole source page contents.

Comment: That is what I had assumed before testing.  The call actually gets an html version of the DOM probably through a document.documentElement.innerHTML; call.