# How do I prevent Javascript from mutating a page in Selenium? How do I download the original page source?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm **not** using Selenium to automate testing, but to automate saving AJAX pages that inject content, even if they require prior authentication to access.

### I tried

**tl;dr: I tried multiple tools for downloading sites with AJAX and gave up because they were hard to work with or simply didn't work.** I'm resorting to using Selenium after trying out *WebHTTrack* (whose GUI wasn't able to start up on my Ubuntu machine + was a headache to provide authentication with in interactive-terminal mode), *`wget`* (which didn't download any of the scripts of stylesheets included on my page, see the bottom for what I tried with wget)... and then I finally gave up after a [promising post](http://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/scraping-ajax-web-pages/) on using a Mozilla XULRunner AJAX scraper called *Crowbar* simply seg-faulted on me. So...

### ended up making my own broken thing in NodeJS and Selenium-WebdriverJS

My NodeJS script uses [selenium-webdriver npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/selenium-webdriver) which is ["officially supported by the main project"](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) to:

- provide login information + do necessary button-clicking & typing for authentication
- download all JS and CSS referenced on target page
- download target page with original JS/CSS file links change to local file paths

Now when I view my test page locally I see double of many page elements because the target site loads HTML snippets into the page each time it's loaded. I use this to download my target page right now:

```
var $;
var getTarget = function () {                                                                                                                                               
    driver.getPageSource().then(function (source) {
        $ = cheerio.load(source.toString());
    }); 
};

var targetHtmlDest = 'test.html';
var writeTarget = function () {
    fs.writeFile(targetHtmlDest, $.html());
}

driver.get(targetSite)
    .then(authenticate)
    .then(getRoot)
    .then(downloadResources)
    .then(writeRoot);
driver.quit();
```

The problem is that the page source I get is the *already modified* page source, instead of the original one. Trying to run `alert("x");window.stop();` within [`driver.executeAsyncScript()` and `driver.executeScript()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html) does nothing.

Comment: Make an additional separate HTTP request from your scraper (bypassing Selenium) to retrieve just the page source, perhaps?

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff I would, if I didn't need to do login to get to my page. The point of using Selenium was to automate that authentication.

Comment: Voting to close this question now, since [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050805/getting-the-raw-source-from-firefox-with-javascript) also asks the same thing. Waiting for a response that actually solves the problem. `innerHTML` gets the _current_ source and not the original source.

Comment: OK. Check out some other tools apart from Selenium, though (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539491/headless-browser-and-scraping-solutions). You can e.g. use PhantomJS with disabled JavaScript, so that page source doesn't get modified by scripts.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff thanks for the link. I'll probably end up going back to using CasperJS in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using Curl to get the page (you can pass authentication in the command) will get you the bare source?
Otherwise you may be able to turn off JavaScript on your test browsers to prevent JS actions from firing.